# Selecting multiple polygons based on common field in a point file (point does not fall within polygon) to perform service area analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I have 2 layers; a point layer defining poll locations (340 points), and a polygon layer defining poll divisions (areas assigned to a poll location) (2079 polygons). Each point relates to one or more polygon. They have a common point ID field. I would like to perform a service area analysis to determine if each point is within a 25 min drive of its associated polygon/polygons.  I would like to use a model to automate the process but I don’t know how to automate selecting multiple polygons for a single point in a related table.
Below is a selected study area with Polygon attributes displayed and related point features selected.
I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

[image]

Comment: Can you please include a sample screenshot showing some of your data?

Comment: Sure. Please see above.

Comment: Have I understood correctly, for each point you have one or more related polygons and they are linked by an ID field? So for example you have a point lets say its ID is 22 you will have for example 3 polygons that are associated with this point and they have a field with a number 22? If this is correct then you need only build and run a [RELATE](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#/Relating_the_attributes_in_one_table_to_another/005s0000002v000000/).

Comment: That is correct. However I run into an issue because I can't perform and SQL query on the related feature based on the attributes of the origin feature. I think I have to use a work around by creating a new point feature with the attribute I want to use for selection in it. Thanks.